# jQuery: change not triggering, neither is click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have a very complicated script, but was able to replicate the changes [in a simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ehes7/3/).

Here is the code locally:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="rangeStart" value="updateMe" /><br/>
<input type="text" class="start-date" value="different" /><br/>
<input type="text" class="start-date" value="data" /><br/>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Press Me" />
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery('#rangeStart').change(function() {
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery('.start-date').each(function () {
        jQuery(this).val(value); 
    });
});;

jQuery('#button').click(function () {
    alert("pressed");
    jQuery('rangeStart').val('new value');
});
```

Clicking the button doesn't even trigger the alert message!  I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I've been staring at it for an hour and cannot figure it out so I'm deferring to [xkcd.com/627](http://xkcd.com/627/) and seeking help.

Thanks!

Comment: You should check for errors in your browser's developer console.

Comment: I did before I submit this.  There weren't any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/Ehes7/4/

You forgot to include the `jQuery` library.

Comment: I was also typing to give the same answer!

Comment: That fixes the OP's JSFiddle but I doubt it fixes the code on their site

Comment: Thank you about the jQuery import reminder, but the values aren't changing in the fields.  The alert triggers now, but none of the fields update for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try it again with a little bit change:

```
$(function(){
  $('#rangeStart').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('.start-date').each(function () {
        $(this).val(value); 
    });
  });;

  $('#button').click(function () {
    alert("pressed");
    $('#rangeStart').val('new value');
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, that updates the rangeStart field, but the .start-date ones still don't change.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, jquery was not loaded in jsfiddle. Better use of "each function" can make code more readable (use arguments).
 http://jsfiddle.net/UY3hE/1/

> $('#rangeStart').change(function() {
>
> ```
>     var value = $(this).val();
>     $('.start-date').each(function (i,itm) {
>         $(itm).val(value); 
>     });
> });
>
> $('#button').click(function () {
>     alert("pressed");
>     $('rangeStart').val('new value');
> });
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Two things need to happen here...

1. Make sure jQuery is loaded **before** your script, eg

   ```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       // your script here
   </script>
   ```
2. Either run your script **after** the elements concerned are part of the document OR (more conventionally), run your script within a [document *ready* event handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), eg

   ```
   jQuery(function($) {
       // your script here
   });
   ```